# Need to add a separator to results

Tags: javascript

What can I add to this code to ensure the results are separated by a 
 or line? When I run the script the results return which each section on top of the othe with no sperataor so it's hard to determine where the next one starts

```
     <code>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // input field descriptions
    var desc = new Array();
    desc['PROC_CODE'] = 'Procedure Code';
    desc['MEDICARE'] = 'Medicare Advantage';
    desc['STATUS'] = 'Procedure';
    desc['ID'] = 'Specialty';
    desc['SYS_APP'] = 'Precert Type';
    desc['SUBMITTER'] = 'Review Type';
    desc['EMAIL'] = 'Guidelines';
    desc['ADD_CPT'] = 'Additional Information for CPT';
    desc['change'] = 'Prior Change Information';

    <!--------->
    desc['PROC_CODE1'] = 'Procedure Code';
    desc['MEDICARE1'] = 'Medicare Advantage';
    desc['STATUS1'] = 'Procedure';
    desc['ID1'] = 'Specialty';
    desc['SYS_APP1'] = 'Precert Type';
    desc['SUBMITTER1'] = 'Review Type';
    desc['EMAIL1'] = 'Guidelines';
    desc['ADD_CPT1'] = 'Additional Information for CPT';
    desc['change1'] = 'Prior Change Information';

    <!--------->
    desc['PROC_CODE2'] = 'Procedure Code';
    desc['MEDICARE2'] = 'Medicare Advantage';
    desc['STATUS2'] = 'Procedure';
    desc['ID2'] = 'Specialty';
    desc['SYS_APP2'] = 'Precert Type';
    desc['SUBMITTER2'] = 'Review Type';
    desc['EMAIL2'] = 'Guidelines';
    desc['ADD_CPT2'] = 'Additional Information for CPT';
    desc['change2'] = 'Prior Change Information';
    <!--------->
    desc['PROC_CODE3'] = 'Procedure Code';
    desc['MEDICARE3'] = 'Medicare Advantage';
    desc['STATUS3'] = 'Procedure';
    desc['ID3'] = 'Specialty';
    desc['SYS_APP3'] = 'Precert Type';
    desc['SUBMITTER3'] = 'Review Type';
    desc['EMAIL3'] = 'Guidelines';
    desc['ADD_CPT3'] = 'Additional Information for CPT';
    desc['change3'] = 'Prior Change Information';
    <!--------->
    desc['PROC_CODE4'] = 'Procedure Code';
    desc['MEDICARE4'] = 'Medicare Advantage';
    desc['STATUS4'] = 'Procedure';
    desc['ID4'] = 'Specialty';
    desc['SYS_APP4'] = 'Precert Type';
    desc['SUBMITTER4'] = 'Review Type';
    desc['EMAIL4'] = 'Guidelines';
    desc['ADD_CPT4'] = 'Additional Information for CPT';
    desc['change4'] = 'Prior Change Information';

    <!--------->
    desc['PROC_CODE5'] = 'Procedure Code';
    desc['MEDICARE5'] = 'Medicare Advantage';
    desc['STATUS5'] = 'Procedure';
    desc['ID5'] = 'Specialty';
    desc['SYS_APP5'] = 'Precert Type';
    desc['SUBMITTER5'] = 'Review Type';
    desc['EMAIL5'] = 'Guidelines';
    desc['ADD_CPT5'] = 'Additional Information for CPT';
    desc['change5'] = 'Prior Change Information';



    function CopyFields(){
        var copytext = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
            copytext += desc[arguments[i]] + ': ' + document.getElementById(arguments[i]).innerText + '\n' ;}
        var tempstore = document.getElementById(arguments[0]).innerText;
    window.clipboardData.setData('Text', copytext + '\n');}  

     function show(ele) {
             var srcElement = document.getElementById(ele);
             if(srcElement != null) {
   if(srcElement.style.display == "block" ) {
          srcElement.style.display= 'none';
    }
        else {
               srcElement.style.display='block';
        }
        return false;
           }
   }</script>
        <code>
```

Here is the call for copyFields()

```
          <code>
          <a href="#" onClick="CopyFields(
          'PROC_CODE','MEDICARE', 'STATUS', 'ID', 'SYS_APP', 'SUBMITTER','EMAIL','ADD_CPT','change',
          'PROC_CODE1','MEDICARE1', 'STATUS1', 'ID1', 'SYS_APP1', 'SUBMITTER1','EMAIL1','ADD_CPT1','change1',
          'PROC_CODE2','MEDICARE2', 'STATUS2', 'ID2', 'SYS_APP2', 'SUBMITTER2','EMAIL2','ADD_CPT2','change2',
          'PROC_CODE3','MEDICARE3', 'STATUS3', 'ID3', 'SYS_APP3', 'SUBMITTER3','EMAIL3','ADD_CPT3','change3',
          'PROC_CODE4','MEDICARE4', 'STATUS4', 'ID4', 'SYS_APP4', 'SUBMITTER4','EMAIL4','ADD_CPT4','change4',
          'PROC_CODE5','MEDICARE5', 'STATUS5', 'ID5', 'SYS_APP5', 'SUBMITTER5','EMAIL5','ADD_CPT5','change5');"><b>Cli              ck To Copy ALL data returned on this page</b></a></code>
```

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: From where you are calling `CopyFields()`?

Comment: @The-Val I've added the call for CopyFields()

Comment: You're instantiating desc as a new Array but using it like an object. I'd fix it to be `desc = {}`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `join` function:

```
var a = ["foo", "goo", "boo"];
console.log(a.join("\n"));
```

Console output:

```
> foo
> goo
> boo
```